# PHP array to JSON having a parameter with a callback function

Tags: javascript, php, json, pannellum

On my PHP script, I have an array similar to this:

```
$panorama = array(
    "default" => array(
        "firstScene" => 2,
        "author" => 'Felipe'
    ), 
    "scenes" => array(
        "circle" => array(
            "title" => "Title 1", 
            "hotSpots" => array(
                "pitch" => "-2.1",
                "createTooltipFunc" => "hotspot"
            )
        )
    )
);
```

This array will be passed to a Javascript funcion, as a json object, like this:

```
pannellum.viewer('panorama', <?php echo json_encode($panorama); ?>);
```

The parameter createTooltipFunc have to receive a callback function named hotspot. So, in the final json, when I pass this PHP array to the Javascript function, this parameter should be like this: **"createTooltipFunc" : hotspot**, without the double quotes. How do I do that?

Just to give more information, I'm trying to create a tour using the plugin **pannellum.js** and I'm geting all the info of the json I need from my mysql DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a Javascript variable in between which keeps the object and update the property before it's using with **pannellum**(Assumes `hotspot` is a variable).

```
//  create Javascript object
var obj = <?php echo json_encode($panorama); ?>;

// update createTooltipFunc proeprty with the variable
// where variable name can be extract from $panorama
obj.scenes.circle.hotSpots.createTooltipFunc = <?php echo $panorama['scenes']['circle']['hotSpots']['createTooltipFunc']; ?>;

pannellum.viewer('panorama', obj);
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: hotspot is not defined

Comment: That didn't work. I have multiple occurences of the createTooltipFunc. It's an array with more levels than the example I gave. I have to give a javascript function to this parameter in order to customize my hotspot.

Comment: @PranavCBalan you can access it using obj.scenes.circle.hotSpots.createTooltipFunc

Comment: So, I have to search and replace the doble quoutes using Javascript?

Comment: @churros :  this is one method

Answer (score 0):

Following Pranav suggestion, I had to put the PHP array into a javascript object and loop through it to find the right node, and then replace the old value for the new, something like this:

```
var objTour = <?php echo json_encode($panorama); ?>;
            for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(objTour.scenes)) {
                var objdadosScene = value;
                for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(objdadosScene)) {
                    if(key == 'hotSpots'){
                        var objHotspot = objdadosScene.hotSpots;
                        for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(objHotspot)) {
                            var objDadosHotspot = value;
                            for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(objDadosHotspot)) {                             
                                objDadosHotspot['createTooltipFunc'] = hotspot;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I don't know if this was the best way to achieve the result, but it's working. Thanks!